# How display my view with partials in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial

I'm learning Rails and I'm trying to use partials to clear my code.

When I refresh the post/new page, the only thing I have is the "Créer un article".
Nothing in my partial _form appears..

I don't understand my mistake, did I miss something?

Here is my view:

```
<h1>Créer un article</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

Here is the  partial:

```
<% form_with model: @post do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Titre</label>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class:'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Slug</label>
    <%= f.text_field :slug, class:'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Contenu</label>
    <%= f.text_area :content, class:'form-control'%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Valider", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <a href="<%= posts_path %>" class="btn btn-secondary">Retour</a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Log from rails local server:

```
Started GET "/posts/new" for ::1 at 2019-12-26 17:38:03 +0100
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML
  Rendering posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (Duration: 20.7ms | Allocations: 2408)
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 22.8ms | Allocations: 2711)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 34.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 7669)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missing equal sign (=) from first line, it should be like this below

```
<%= form_with model: @post do |f| %>
```

Comment: My bad. Needed fresh eyes to see it ! Thank you